# Deploying Django app to AWS EC2 using Nginx and Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, git, amazon-web-services, nginx

I am a newbie to web I developed a small web app using python and Django things are working fine with local development server. Now I want to deploy my app to an AWS EC2 instance with Nginx and Gunicorn. Every tutorial I found on the internet explains things using a linux platform. Unfortunately, I am using a windows.

I have never used Git or Linux, will I be able to do things from Windows machine itself?

Comment: This is the first time I am asking something on stackoverflow, I will consider your advise from next time onwards Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PUtty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) and follow [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html).

After connecting to you linux instance everything command will be on linux.
It does not matter which platform you are using, just make sure on AWS, you should create linux instace and follow those tutorial on deploying with gUnicorn and Nginx.